# Bootstrap tabs refreshing page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just trying to implement basic bootstrap tab functionality, but whenever I click on a tab the page refreshes instead of just show/hide the appropriate content. What is causing this issue?

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href="#forcast" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Forecast</a></li>
            <li><a href="#month" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">By Month</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ytd" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">YTD</a></li>
            <li><a href="#age" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">By Age</a></li>
            <li><a href="#overdue" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Months Overdue</a></li>
            <li class="pull-right secondary-nav"><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="collapsedkpi=!collapsedkpi"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></i> Filters</button></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="forcast">
            <div id="chartdiv"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="month">
            Hello Month
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="ytd">
            Hello YTD
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="age">
            Hello Age
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="overdue">
            Hello Overdue
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: is there a js error?

Answer (score 0):

that means your javascript isn't working or loaded.

open your console and look at the error message

make sure you have this line included

```
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

Comment: bootstrap.min.js is included and console shows no errors

Comment: yes..had something similar, but changed to your code just to verify.

Comment: well there isnt much to do if you provide limited info on what is going on.. why dont you create an example of your attempts on js fiddle.

Comment: Here is the plunker...http://plnkr.co/edit/3pqsccyOMGMPW0pxD5mc?p=preview and it works, but my page still refreshes when tab is clicked

Comment: then it is issue on your page not related to this block of code.. url?